# Can't show content of the subpage (AngularJS routing)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I opening the main page I can't see the content of "home.html" file.

> http://127.0.0.1:60590/#/home.html

And the same problem is when I open the "contact.html"

> http://127.0.0.1:60590/#/contact.html

file because it redirect's me to the "home.html" again.

**I think the "app.js" code is valid.**

```
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'view/home.html'
        })
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'view/contact.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home.html'
        });
}]);
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl" ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>kedar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib\angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib\app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
        <main ng-view></main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the `.html`, try with only `http://127.0.0.1:60590/#/contact`

Comment: what error you are getting in console ?

Comment: There's no error in console. I removed but still the same, redirecting to the home.html. But other strange thing is no showing content of the home.html on the home.html page.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/mtV62/1070/
it's basically what you want

Comment: Okay but I want to do it by this way with my own files etc. It must work because it is on YouTube tutorial. Can you take a look on app.js code? Is it valid?

Comment: Okay I found the problem. I needed to delete ".html" in "otherwise" in app.js file. Thank You guys for help.

Comment: post it as an answer and accept it